# Catch img tag and change image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one problem with javascript code. I know how to do using jQuery but I must use js for this. I need when someone click on first div to catch image "show.png" in first div and change it with another

I have HTML code like this (this repeat couple time with different ID)

```
<div class="clickdown" onclick="return toggleMe('p_202')">
    <table>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td width="20px">
                <img src="images/show.png" align="top" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>textttext</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/btn_New.png" alt="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="p_202" class="clickdown_content" style="display: none;">
    <p>
    texttexttexttexttexttexttext
    </p>
</div>
```

and exist Javascript code for expand and colapse second div.

```
function toggleMe(a) {
   var e = document.getElementById(a);
   if (!e) return true;
   if (e.style.display == "none") {
       e.style.display = "block"
   } else {
       e.style.display = "none"
   }
   return true;
}
```

FYI Don't tell me "This code are a..ul" - I know it but I have request just to add, not to change any.

So I can't add ID and use this with getElementByID()

I try something like this but that don't work (Here I'm hiding image just to see does ti work)

```
function toggleMe(a) {
    var ttable = document.getElementsByTagName("table").item(0);
    var ttr = ttable.getElementsByTagName("tr").item(0);
    var ttd = ttr.getElementsByTagName("td").item(0);
    vari = ttd.getElementsByTagName("img").item(0);
    if (i.src == "images/btn_New.png") {
        i.style.display == "none"
    } else {
        i.style.display = "block"
    };
    var e = document.getElementById(a);
    if (!e) return true;
    if (e.style.display == "none") {
        e.style.display = "block"
    } else {
        e.style.display = "none"
    }
    return true;
}
```

Resume:

I must leave old code html and javascript and add new javascript code

Comment: Looks like you're missing a space on `vari`

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
function toggleMe(a) {
  var ttable = document.getElementsByTagName("table").item(0);
  var ttr = ttable.getElementsByTagName("tr").item(0);
  var ttd = ttr.getElementsByTagName("td").item(0);
  var i = ttd.getElementsByTagName("img").item(0);
  if (i.src.indexOf("images/show.png") !== -1) {
    i.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    i.style.display = "block";
  }

  var e = document.getElementById(a);
  if (!e) return true;
  if (e.style.display == "none") {
    e.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    e.style.display = "none";
  }
  return true;
}
```

You have to use indexOf because in attribute **src** you have the whole url.

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NmMaL5?p=preview)

Image you can easy change in this way:

```
i.src = "images/newShow.png";
```

Comment: Yes it's work but if I include this on my site that don't work. In ispect element I can see error message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read propertly 'css' of null. By the way how can I write img.src == "picture.jpg" because i.src.indexOf("images/show.png") !== -1 don't complete a job

Comment: I see what is problem. Problem is in this row var ttable = document.getElementsByTagName("table").item(0); Document must change with sometnihk because I have a lot of divs with this js and that must work on each. I tried with this. but that don't stil work

Comment: I think that you can see `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`. This means that `document.getElementById(a);` is null - check why?. If you write image use only one equal char `i.src = "picture.jpg"` and you can test it by using `i.src.indexOf("picture.jpg")`.

Comment: This is because i don't select first element correctly. ID witch i send is for another element. I must find a way to select element who call function without sending any information (id,class,...) trough function. If it's possible please tell me.

Comment: To pass element which call your function use `return toggleMe(this)` and in `function toggleMe(a)` don't need user `var e = document.getElementById(a);` because `a` is your element. So you can use `a.style.display = "block"`

Comment: a isn't ID for this element, it's ID for next element witch I must toggle. You can take a look structure of code above. Resume : I send ID for another div but i must select div who call function.

Comment: You can use: `var div2 = document.getElementsByTagName("div").item(1);` or `var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName("clickdown_content").item(0);`

Comment: I have a lot of divs like that on one page so I must catch start div for each div where I click. This is ok if I have just this one but that don't work in my case